# How to identify python in windows 10

Tags: python

Recently I have install python 3.9.9 in my windows 10.it want show the path

I have typed cmd promt "Wchich Python" it want show

Comment: what are you getting in the cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Just type **python** or **python3** in cmd

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your cmd

> where python

It will show you the path of all installed python in your device

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple command,

```
where Python
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Command Prompt, either `which python` or `where python` will print the path to your python executable.

If `which python` or `where python` does not show the path to your Python executable it is likely that it is not in your PATH variable.

To add your executable to the PATH variable you, search for Environment Variables in the Settings application. This will open the Advanced tab in System Properties. Click the Environment Variables button towards the bottom. You can then edit the PATH variable to include the path to your Python executable. Once you have applied the changes and restarted Command Prompt you can then run `which python` or `where python` to confirm your changes have taken effect.